# How come singleton class make multiple objects?

Tags: java, singleton

I took this example from a tutorial. 
 Given below class was created to restrict multiple objects creation in same class.

```
package interview;

public class Test1 {

    private static Test1 tstObj = null;

    private Test1() {
    }

    public static Test1 createObject() {
        if (tstObj == null) {
            tstObj = new Test1();
        }
        return tstObj;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Singleton class Example");
    }
}
```

But when I tried to create multiple objects from the same class in another class in same package I got succeeded.

```
package interview;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 myobject = Test1.createObject();
        myobject.display();
        Test1 myobject1 = Test1.createObject();
        myobject1.display();
        Test1 myobject2 = Test1.createObject();
        myobject2.display();
    }
}
```

How come this happened or am I not understanding the consepnt of multiple object creation ???

Please help.

Comment: Read the code for `createObject`.  What happens the second time this is called? What is the value of `tstObj` on the second and subsequent calls? What is being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second and third calls to `Test1#createObject()` are not actually creating another instance of the singleton class, q.v. the code for the constructor:

```
public static Test1 createObject() {
    // create a single instance the first time around
    if (tstObj == null) {
        tstObj = new Test1();
    }
    // otherwise return the instance which already exists
    return tstObj;
}
```

Note carefully that the `if` statement only instantiates the singleton if the reference be `null`, which ideally should only happen the very first time your app calls `createObject()`.